# Command line to recursively delete files but excluding a certain file

Tags: command-line, batch-file, dos

I need to delete files of a certain type (.zip files, say) from a folder, and all of its sub-folders, using the command line. Ideally I am looking for something that can be run as a .bat file in Windows.

I know there is a /S switch for the DEL command to look in sub-folders, but to add to the challenge I need to exclude files of a certain name ("Backup.zip" as an example).

Is there a way to delete files recursively but exclude files of a certain name. It will not be practical in my situation to explicitly list all the file names I want to delete, only the files of the matching type I don't want to delete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A nice trick: make the [files you want to exclude read-only](http://www.computing.net/answers/dos/excluding-folders-when-using-del-s/16548.html)!

`DEL /S` will not delete read-only file.

The following script does not do *exactly* what you want (see my remarks below) but shows you how read-only files can be used to avoid deletion.

```
@ECHO OFF
:: This example supposes your first parameter is
:: the relative path to the folder to be deleted
:: and the second is the relative path (from the
:: the target folder) of the one to be excluded
:: Notice that this will only work if the folders
:: are in the working drive, if not, you ll
:: have to specify full paths

IF "%1"=="" GOTO ERROR
IF "%2"=="" GOTO ERROR
IF NOT EXIST %1\NUL GOTO ERROR
CD %1
IF NOT EXIST %2\NUL GOTO ERROR
ECHO Starting up the deletion process
ECHO. * Setting attributes
attrib %1\*.mp3 -r -s -h > NUL
attrib %2\*.mp3 +r > NUL
ECHO. * Deleting files
del /s %1\*.mp3
ECHO. * Reseting attributes
attrib %2\*.mp3 -r > NUL
ECHO.
ECHO Operation completed!
ECHO.
GOTO END

:ERROR
ECHO Parameters:
ECHO. Param1 -> target folder
ECHO. Param2 -> folder to be ignored
ECHO.
GOTO END

:END
```

Note: you can adapt this script in order to ignore not just a sub-folder but all files of given type:

```
attrib /S *.xxx +r > NUL
```

will in effect help you to exclude all 'xxx' files of the current directory *and all sub-directories* (hence the `/S` option).

---

Note: the "`> NUL`" part is a **[redirection](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)** often used to hide standard output, instead of displaying it on screen.
It can be dangerous if used too often (in a large loop with different paths involved, for instance) since it is a **device**, and like all devices (`AUX`, `COMn`, `LPTn`, `NUL` and `PRN`):

- opening a device will claim one file handle. However, unlike files, devices will never be closed until reboot.
- each device exists in every directory on every drive, so if you used redirection to `NUL` in, say, `C:\` and after that you use it again in `C:\TEMP`, you'll lose another file handle.

Comment: I don't yet understand the > NUL bit, but I like the idea of setting the attributes. Cheers!

Comment: interesting! notice that rd /s your_directory also erases system and hidden files

Answer (score 4):

Just do this, easy

1. windows button + r
2. type `cmd` and hit enter
3. Navigate to parent directory:
   type `c:` or `d:` (or letter of the drive you want to navigate to)

   type `dir` to see a list of that directory's contents ( `dir /ah` to see hidden files )

   then to change directory, type `cd xxxx` ( xxxx = directory name )

   Repeat 4&5 until you get to the directory where you want to run the batch delete

   then type your pattern. Something like: `del /S /ah *.jpg` and hit enter. It will run through all sub-directories, and remove all visible and hidden files that are .jpg files

*****   is a wildcard
**/S**    deletes from all subfolders
**/ah**    a = select files based on attribute, h = hidden

**Example:** to delete those annoying .DS_Store files that appear when you copy from Mac to Windows, run:

`del /S /ah .DS_Store`

or

`del /S /ah ._*`

which will get all the 'duplicate' hidden files that are also created when copying from Mac to Windows.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily loop a set of files and perform a command on each one, like this:

```
set match=D:\blah\M*.zip
for %%x in (%match%) do (
del %%x
)
```

Then I think you need to read this article on how to manipulate strings in DOS:
http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use below:

```
forfiles /p C:\temp-new /s /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE del @file"
```

[TechNet Referenceenter link description here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the 'forfiles' command could be of use

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This script will delete all .zip files from a folder (and subfolders), BUT ONLY IF the file name does not contain the word "backup", or "Backup" or "BACKUP", etc.

```
# Script DeleteZip.txt
var str folder, filelist, file
cd $folder
lf -r -n "*.zip" > $filelist
while ($filelist <> "")
do
    lex "1" $filelist > $file
    # Does this $file contain the word "backup" ? Do case independent search (-c option).
    if ( { sen -c "^backup^" $file } <= 0 )
        system del ("\""+$file+"\"")
    endif
done
```

Script is in biterscripting ( http://www.biterscripting.com ). Save the script in file C:/Scripts/DeleteZip.txt. Run the script as

```
script "C:/Scripts/DeleteZip.txt" folder("C:/testfolder")
```

Will do the delete operation on folder C:/testfolder and all its subfolders, at all levels.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way that you need:

```
FORFILES /P "DIRECTORY" /S /M SEARCHMASK /C "cmd /c if @file neq \"FILE_TO_EXCLUDE\" del /f @file"
```

You still can adapt the command to your need to exclude specific files and/or by date. More details in the 'forfiles' documentation below.

*https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles*